# Is there a way to stop traffic to RDS other than stopping application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have created route53 record for my rds endpoint and was wondering if there is a way to stop traffic to rds by configuring weighted policy? RDS has only single endpoint.

Comment: Bit confusing but you can stop a rds instance itself if you dont want to stop traffic on the application itself. Also you can create Inbound rules to allow traffic only from specific IP address.

Comment: Using DNS to stop access isn't ideal... The Time-to-Live would still persist the DNS record, so when it is changed it will not immediately impact users who have the DNS entry cached. Can I ask... _WHY_ do you wish to "stop traffic to RDS"?

Comment: I need to stop traffic so that I can switch it to new endpoint. And start traffic back once the new endpoint is updated so that there is no data loss in between this switch.

Answer (score 0):

It does not really make much sense to have only one endpoint and put weighted routing on it. If you have **multiple** endpoints and want to distribute traffic unevenly, weighted routing may be useful.

If you configure a record in Route 53 (e.g. A, CNAME), you have the option to choose a weighted routing policy. And you also have the option to assign a weight of 0, meaning that Route 53 stops responding to DNS queries for that record. Below is a picture that shows how to do this:

[image]

Comment: So in case of single endpoint, if we apply weighted policy of 0 it will still send traffic to this record?

Comment: No it will stop responding to DNS queries for that record, so no traffic.

Comment: I tested this but I was able to telnet and connect to this route53 record using mysql after applying weighted policy. Hence I was confused if it works